# I want to insert these data into my sql database using xampp.. I got this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'victor' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`firstName`, `lastName` , `gender`, `address` , `phoneNumber`, `emailAddress`, `userName` , `password`) VALUES
(1, `victor`, `Agbani`, `male`, `ajegunle`, `879889234`, `victoragbani@hotmail.com`,`victo` ,`agbani`),
(2, `Moses`, `Agogu`, `male`, `festac`, `879889235`, `mosesagogu@hotmail.com`, `mosko` ,`agogu`),
(3, `John`, `Jude`, `male`, `mile2`, `879889236`, `johnjude@hotmail.com`, `johny` ,`jude`),
(4, `Peter`, `Andrew`, `male`, `lagos`, `879889237`, `peterandrew@hotmail.com`, `peto` ,`andrew`),
(5, `Mathew`, `Mark`, `male`, `oyo`, `879889238`, `mathewmark@hotmail.com`, `math` ,`mark`),
(6, `James`, `Innocent`, `male`, `lafia`, `879889239`, `jamesinnocent@hotmail.com`, `jamsy`, `innocent`),
(7, `Paul`, `Animazu`, `male`, `ekiti`, `879889230`, `paulanimzu@hotmail.com`, `paulo`, `animazu`),
(8, `Mary`, `John`, `female`, `kwara`, `879889231`, `marylove@hotmail.com`,`maria`,  `john`),
(9, `Deborah`, `Agbolu`, `female`, `abuja`,`879889228`, `deborah234@hotmail.com`, `debo`, `agbolu`),
(10, `Esther`, `Agabi`, `female`, `ondo`, `8798892229`, `esther123@hotmail.com`, `esto`, `agabi`)
```

Comment: remove ` from your first line for all columns

Comment: Learn the difference between backticks and single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape table and column names with backticks. But strings with quotes

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`firstName`, ...) 
VALUES (1, 'victor', ...
           ^------^--------------here
```

Comment: Strictly speaking the SQL standard specifies double quotes for identifiers.

Comment: Thank you. it works now......